# Tabulator - I want to have multiple images in a column which are clickable

Tags: tabulator

I know tabulator will allow you to use a image in a column but what I need is to be able to have multiple images in a column and those images need to be able to use the onclick in order to do something.

For example, I have a column called actions and in the that column I have image options like Start, Stop, Pause or could be Edit and delete etc.

I have this with normal datatables but was wondering if this can be done with Tabulator. I really like tabulator and so I have been playing around with it to see if it would fit all my needs before I adopt it.

I looked around the documentation but cant seem to find anything that will help out unless I am just missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a [custom formatter](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/format#format-custom) on the actions column.  There are a few ways to do this but here is one example:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Billy Bob',
    age: '12',
    gender: 'male',
    height: 1,
    col: 'red',
    dob: '',
    cheese: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mary May',
    age: '1',
    gender: 'female',
    height: 2,
    col: 'blue',
    dob: '14/05/1982',
    cheese: true
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Margret Marmajuke',
    age: '16',
    gender: 'female',
    height: 5,
    col: 'yellow',
    dob: '31/01/1999'
  }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
  data: data,
  columns: [{
      title: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      field: 'age'
    },
    {
      title: 'Gender',
      field: 'gender'
    },
    {
      title: 'Height',
      field: 'height'
    },
    {
      title: 'Favourite Color',
      field: 'col'
    },
    {
      title: '',
      field: 'actions',
      formatter: (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) => {
        const playButton = document.createElement("img")
        const pauseButton = document.createElement("img")
        const stopButton = document.createElement("img")

        playButton.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiIGNsYXNzPSJsdWNpZGUgbHVjaWRlLXBsYXktY2lyY2xlIj48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMiIgY3k9IjEyIiByPSIxMCIvPjxwb2x5Z29uIHBvaW50cz0iMTAgOCAxNiAxMiAxMCAxNiAxMCA4Ii8+PC9zdmc+')
        pauseButton.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiIGNsYXNzPSJsdWNpZGUgbHVjaWRlLXBhdXNlLWNpcmNsZSI+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIiIGN5PSIxMiIgcj0iMTAiLz48bGluZSB4MT0iMTAiIHgyPSIxMCIgeTE9IjE1IiB5Mj0iOSIvPjxsaW5lIHgxPSIxNCIgeDI9IjE0IiB5MT0iMTUiIHkyPSI5Ii8+PC9zdmc+')
        stopButton.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiIGNsYXNzPSJsdWNpZGUgbHVjaWRlLXN0b3AtY2lyY2xlIj48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMiIgY3k9IjEyIiByPSIxMCIvPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI2IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjYiIHg9IjkiIHk9IjkiLz48L3N2Zz4=')

        playButton.addEventListener('click', () => { start(cell.getData().name) })
        pauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => { pause(cell.getData().name) })
        stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => { stop(cell.getData().name) })

        onRendered(() => {
          cell.getElement().appendChild(playButton)
          cell.getElement().appendChild(pauseButton)
          cell.getElement().appendChild(stopButton)
        })

        return cell.getValue()
      }
    }
  ]
})

function start(name) {
  alert(name + ' started.')
}

function pause(name) {
  alert(name + ' paused.')
}

function stop(name) {
  alert(name + ' stopped.')
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```